# python including back slash before and inside a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

My final goal is to get [\'2\',\'3\'] when I am running the following code:

```
results=['2','3']
launchArgs=[]
for thing in results:
    thing="'"+thing+"'"
    THING=thing.replace("'","\'")
    launchArgs.append(THING)
print(launchArgs)
```

However, I am getting

```
["\'2\'", "\'3\'"]
```

What should I do?

Comment: It is a requirement for a pipeline.

Comment: The output you've shown is the same thing. The double quotes just represent that you're printing strings

Comment: If you're trying to pass quoted arguments to some command, though, you shouldn't need escape characters... Please show an example of this "pipeline"

Answer (score 0):

"[\'{}\', \'{}\']".format(2, 3)
i think you should put your brackets inside "", because i never saw this [\'\'], only inside string "[\'\']"

Comment: What if a list is actually wanted, not a String?

Comment: \'2\' looks like escaping, do you try input [2, 3], ["2", "3"] or ['2', '3'], ["\\'2\\'", "\\'3\\'"]?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i think you should try this: ["\\\'2\\\'", "\\\'3\\\'"] - one backslash for escaping backslash, and third backslash for escaping '. Try this

Comment: It's not my question... I think you should comment above asking what the question really is trying to do

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. Anyway i think there something gonna wrong, i don't saw keys with \'